# Pass data from Activity to Fragment on finish

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I have a scenario in which I am starting an Activity from a Fragment. In the Activity, I have to send some data back to the fragment. For this, I am using `startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)` to start the Activity from the Fragment and then catching the result in `onActivityResult()`.

Although this code is working fine for me, the problem is that I am using `SceneTransitionAnimation` to animate an `ImageView` from Fragment to Activity. This requires a bundle to be passed from Fragment to Activity. The problem is that `startActivityForResult()` only takes two parameters in Fragments, so the animation is breaking.

So, I want to ask how I can make sure that I get the data back from the Activity while keeping the animation working? Is there any other way through which I can send data from Activity to Fragment?

**P.S-** I can use `SharedPreferences` and save the data in Activity, finish it, and in Fragment's `onResume()` read the data from `SharedPreferences`. However, I want to avoid using it.

**Update:-**

```
// This is the shared view
final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivProperty);
final Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PropertyDetailsScreen.class);
final View sharedView = imageView;
final String transitionName = getString(R.string.square_blue_name);
// This is the animation
final ActivityOptionsCompat transitionActivityOptions = ActivityOptionsCompat
                    .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(), sharedView, transitionName);
// Getting bundle from the animation
final Bundle bundle = transitionActivityOptions.toBundle();
// Starting the activity with animation
getActivity().startActivity(intent, bundle);
```

Comment: use setResult() in activity and in fragment , access it in onResume() method

Comment: I am already using it. I have specified that but it is breaking the animation since I can't pass in bundle as the third parameter. I want all of it to work, I am able to achieve it partially.

Comment: Than use sharedpreference or broadcast receiver

Comment: make that data variable static and get values in onResume()

Comment: @ShoebSiddique static should not be used in such a way since there are scenarios where it might become null and introduce a bug. So, i avoid it in general.

Comment: @AnandSavjani I am aware of `SharedPreferences` and `Broadcast` receiver but both of there are a bit much when we only need to pass small data. I was hoping of more robust solution like we use interfaces for data communication.

Comment: Use a global static bean or variable which is accessible at everywhere . So in activity set its value and in fragment retrieve it

Comment: before finishing activity, setResult (int resultCode, Intent data), where you can pass bundle in intent data and can be accessed in onActivityResult.

Comment: @Harry I have already written in the question that I have done this and I am able to get the data through it. However, in fragment's `startActivityForResult()` there isn't option to add bundle as a third parameter, which is breaking the animation. So, I was thinking of some other way to pass the data.

Answer (score 0):

> This requires a bundle to be passed from Fragment to Activity. The problem is that startActivityForResult() only takes two parameters in Fragments

You can pass bundle to next activity even if you are using `startActivityForResult`

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(NextActivity.class, this);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    ...
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: I have tried that but in that case the animation is not working. The bundle isn't a normal bundle, but a bundle of `SceneTransitionAnimation` which when passed that way isn't working.

Comment: Can you post the code how you are setting bundle of SceneTransitionAnimation both in case of `startActivityForResult` and just `startActivity`?

Comment: Can you please see the update question now? In this case, I have the animation running properly but I can't get the data back. Also, using `getActivity()` with `startActivityForResult()` means that the result will come in the `Activity` and not in the `Fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

Use  getter,setter method. Set data in activity and get that data in fragment.

Comment: Create a custom class define the type of variable in that class and then generate getter, setter method  for those variable. use object of that class to access of those method

Comment: How will I pass the object of that class from Activity to fragment?

Comment: Create that custom class serializable and the object with the help of intent from activity to fragment.

Comment: @Rohan kandwal if you satisfy  with answer then please tick  it.

Comment: I'll wait to see if more prominent answer comes, if not, will mark your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using **ActivityCompat** you can acheive same,[as mentioned here in documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#startActivityForResult%28android.app.Activity,%20android.content.Intent,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle%29) its mentioned we can pass bundle in  **startActivityForResult**.

Comment: I know that but how will it help in the Fragment?

Comment: it seems like.. it should